# Android Gstreamer local display video lags after starting rtmpsink

Tags: android, stream, video-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I am working on Android app

1. where I have incoming video source in rtsp stream( h265/hevc )
2. source rtsp server have problem only allows **one connection**
3. I want to play rtsp stream and also stream it to rtmp server (antmedia).

   Simple view is as follows

   ```
   [rtsp server] ---> [split] ---> [display]
                              L--> [rtmp stream]
   ```

Current progress:

I used gstreamer and its tutorial 3 code and modify its pipeline as follows

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("rtspsrc location=rtsp://<local_server_ip>:8554/main.265 latency=50 udp-reconnect=1 timeout=5000000 ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! parsebin sink-caps=\"video/x-h265,width=1280,height=720,stream-format=hvc1\" ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink  sync=false t. ! valve drop=true name=liveStrmValve ! queue max-size-buffers=0 silent=true ! parsebin sink-caps=\"video/x-h265,width=1280,height=720,stream-format=hvc1\" ! avdec_h265 ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=25/1 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! queue ! flvmux streamable=true skip-backwards-streams=true ! rtmpsink location=\"rtmp://<server_ip>/LiveApp/<key> live=true\" sync=false async=false", &error);
```

Where streaming is controlled by valve name=liveStrmValve, property drop.

**Problem I am facing :**

1. If the valve is droping(**drop=false**). local video playing is smooth and realtime.
2. If I start valve (from java ui button to jni funtion). valve start and I get stream at **Antmedia server** stream is **good** having 8sec delay.
3. But while streaming **local display video start laging**. and lag get **increases** as there is lot of movment in frames.
4. if I stop live streaming to rtmp server( valve **drop=true**). the **lagged video** **start playing fast** and match the **real time feed** and work smoothly.

**Android :**

```
armeabi-v7a
minSdk 25
targetSdk 33
ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
```

Gstreamer : gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.22.6

My implementation:

- I am getting **rtsp** stream encoded **h264/hevc**. I have used hardwared decoder by **changing rank** before creating pipe. this is only to display video feed on **autovideosink**

  **tee t. ->parsebin -> decodebin3 -> autovideosink**
- for stream video to server, I have tee split stream. then decode

  **t. -> h265decode -> video rate+scale -> encode h264 -> parse -> flvmix -> rtmpsink**

Some errors and warning by gstreamer:

```
After pipe start
w : ../gst-libs/gst/video/video-info.c:762:gst_video_info_to_caps invalid matrix 0 for RGB format, using RGB

w : ../libs/gst/base/gstaggregator.c:2146:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<flvmux0> Latency query failed

w : amcvideodec-omxqcomvideodecoderhevc0: Too old frames, bug in decoder -- please file a bug

w : ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideodecoder.c:3154:gst_video_decoder_prepare_finish_frame:<amcvideodec-omxqcomvideodecoderhevc0> decreasing timestamp (0:00:00.056677084 < 0:00:03.382351466)

After stream start
e : :0: Could not find ref with POC 54
w : ../gst-libs/gst/video/video-info.c:201:validate_colorimetry Need to specify a color matrix when using YUV format (I420)
w : ../gst-libs/gst/video/video-info.c:516:gst_video_info_from_caps invalid colorimetry, using default
```

**Need help :**

1. what could be the cause of local video lagging if stream is live
2. is it possible to use **separate clock** for each branch from tee
3. I have tried to send video on **udpsink** and receive it on other branch **udpsrc** then stream to rtmp server but there is **glitches** in video at antmedia server.
4. is there **any other library I can use here**. single connection, split stream display and stream to rtmp server at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I come up with following solution**
Pipe 1 (main pipe display video)

```
 String RtspH264Url= "rtspsrc location="
         + CameraSettingParameter.getRtspURL() + // camera RTSP Url
         " latency=100 udp-reconnect=1 " +
         "timeout=5000000 wait-for-keyframe=1 name=rtspSrc ! " +
         "rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true " +
         "latency=100 ! parsebin " +
         "sink-caps=\"video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,stream-format=byte-stream\" ! " +
         "tee name=t t. ! queue ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink name=video-sink sync=false " +
         "t. ! queue ! tcpserversink port=5002 sync=true ";
```

Now I get video on tpc port 5002
Pipe 2 (stream video to server)

```
String streamingH264Url =  "tcpclientsrc  port=5002 ! " +
    "capsfilter caps=\"video/x-h264, " +
    "media=(string)video," +
    "clock-rate=(int)90000, " +
    "width=(int)1280, " +
    "height=(int)720," +
    "framerate=30/1, " +
    "payload=(int)96, " +
    "encoding-name=(string)H264, " +
    "stream-format=(string)byte-stream\" ! " +
    "queue " +
    "max-size-buffers=600 " +
    "max-size-time=90000000000 ! " +
    "decodebin ! " +
    "videoconvert ! " +
    "videoscale ! " +
    "videorate ! " +
    "video/x-raw," +
    "width="+ videoWidth +","+//1280
    "height="+ videoHeight+","+ //720
    "framerate="+String.valueOf(CameraSettingParameter.getFrameRate())+"/1 ! " +
    "x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast " +
    "tune=zerolatency ! " +
    "h264parse ! " +
    "flvmux streamable=true ! " +
    "rtmpsink location=\""+ streamingServerUrl +" live=true\" sync=false";
```

Now both pipe line work independently. Without making lags in clocks.